# Is there a function or property like css-zIndex in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, z-index, displayobject

I want to control which DisplayObject is displayed on the front or on the back.
I can control that with zIndex style in css.

How can I do that in as?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [`setChildIndex()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#setChildIndex%28%29)

Here's a quick function that will let you place something at the highest depth:

```
function toTop(child:DisplayObject):void
{
    if(child.parent)
    {
        child.setChildIndex(
            child.parent.numChildren - 1
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: you could remove `container` and just use `child.parent` :)

Comment: @divillysausages I like your style.

Comment: also, if you want to put it to top, `child.parent.addChild(child)` will do the trick ;)

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this in Flex 4.5 (which use addElement instead of addChild) ?

Comment: @back2dos Correct, but that example wouldn't demonstrate the use of setChildIndex very well.

Comment: @Marty Thanks! At first I couldn't understand why `child.setChildIndex(child.parent.numChildren - 1);` moves the child to top because a child which index is `numChildren - 1` should already exist. But the document of `setChildIndex()` which you linked to was helpful to understand why that works.

Answer (score 3):

To control the z-order of the displayObjects use setChildIndex().

Lowest indexed children are displayed at the bottom.
Highest indexed children are displayed at the top.

To change the zorder of the children, use setChildIndex, to illustrate:

```
var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
var child1:Sprite = new Sprite();
var child2:Sprite = new Sprite();
var child3:Sprite = new Sprite();

container.addChild(child1); // bottom 
container.addChild(child2); // middle
container.addChild(child3); // top  
container.setChildIndex(child3,0); // child3 would now be at the bottom
```

Answer (score 2):

There are even more options than only setting the 'z-index', you have full control on the layers:

```
getChildAt(index:int):DisplayObject
```

Gets an object from certain index

```
getChildIndex(child:DisplayObject):int
```

Gets a index from certain object

```
addChild(child:DisplayObject):DisplayObject
addChildAt(child:DisplayObject, index:int):DisplayObject
```

Adds a object on top (addChild) or at certain index (addChildAt)

```
swapChildren(child1:DisplayObject, child2:DisplayObject):DisplayObject
swapChildrenAt(index1:int, index2:int):void
```

Swap objects with eachother of by its 'z-index'

Comment: Nice, I forgot and hardly use that other function 'swapChildren'. usually I am always sorting one particular item.